# PostgreSQL: How can I get all records (users) without primary address?

Tags: sql, postgresql

To explain the problem effectively below is the schema and query example:

---

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.4)**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial,
  username VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO USERS (username) VALUES 
('user 1'), ('user 2'), ('user 3'), ('user 4');

CREATE TABLE addresses (
  id serial,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  street VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  is_primary BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);

INSERT INTO addresses (user_id, street, is_primary) VALUES
(1, 'address 1', false), (1, 'address 2', false), (1, 'address 3', false),
(2, 'address 4', false), (2, 'address 5', false), (2, 'address 6', false),
(3, 'address 7', false), (3, 'address 8', false), (3, 'address 9', true),
(4, 'address 10', false), (4, 'address 11', true), (4, 'address 12', false);
```

---

**Query**

```
select * from addresses;
```

```
| id  | user_id | street     | is_primary |
| --- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1   | 1       | address 1  | false      |
| 2   | 1       | address 2  | false      |
| 3   | 1       | address 3  | false      |
| 4   | 2       | address 4  | false      |
| 5   | 2       | address 5  | false      |
| 6   | 2       | address 6  | false      |
| 7   | 3       | address 7  | false      |
| 8   | 3       | address 8  | false      |
| 9   | 3       | address 9  | true       |
| 10  | 4       | address 10 | false      |
| 11  | 4       | address 11 | true       |
| 12  | 4       | address 12 | false      |
```

---

**Expected Result**

Id like to get these records below:

```
| id  | user_id | street     | is_primary |
| --- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1   | 1       | address 1  | false      |
| 2   | 1       | address 2  | false      |
| 3   | 1       | address 3  | false      |
| 4   | 2       | address 4  | false      |
| 5   | 2       | address 5  | false      |
| 6   | 2       | address 6  | false      |
```

---

**What I Tried So Far Was**

Use the example of `ALL` and `HAVING` clause and honestly aside from that my knowledge on SQL scripting is very limited so I can't figure out any logic how to get the correct result.

Comment: While @sticky_bit's answer works, I hope you have validation to make sure that a user can only have 1 primary address (e.g. through a trigger or exclusion constraint). Another option would be to add a `primary_address` attribute to your `user` table (with the appropriate foreign key), to enforce that a user can only have 1 primary address. This would also simplify your query: `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE primary_address IS NULL`.

Comment: Good pointer @Zack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery that searches for a primary address of the user.

```
SELECT a1.*
       FROM addresses a1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM addresses a2
                                WHERE a2.user_id = a1.user_id
                                      AND is_primary);
```

Comment: Its harder than I could imagine! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I want to note that you can do this with window functions:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             bool_or(a.is_primary) over (partition by a.user_id) as any_primary
      from addresses a
     ) a
where not any_primary;
```

For more information on the `BOOL_OR` function, see the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.25.4.2.2.6.1.1).

Comment: I edited to fix a typo and add a link to the documentation. Feel free to keep your version. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to query like this:

```sql
select * from addresses 
where is_primary = false 
  and user_id not in (select user_id from addresses where is_primary = true);
```